# Backbone View cant exit click event validation

Tags: validation, backbone.js, view

I use a two-stage browser validation, bootstrap-acknowledgeinput makes sure the field is not blank and jqBootstrapValidate in handles true validation and REGEX patterns and adds a below the form field in brown text which gives the error.When the user clicks the [REGISTER] button I detect that and send JSon data to some PHP which does server side validation. If this fails, it populates text in different

tags which show server side input data errors.

I am detecting the error tags, but I can't figure out how to exit the click event and just sit
on the incomplete form waiting for the user to correct the client side validation.

```
var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

         el: $("#container"),

          events: {
                   'click .btn-primary'   : 'saveClient',    
                   'blur input#loginname'      : 'userCheck'
          },

     saveClient: function (e) {

          $('ul li').each(function(index){
             if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){
                 alert('client side error found');
                 return false;
                }
            });

            var loginname  = $('#loginname').val(),
              password  = $('#password').val(),
              first     = $('#first').val(),
              last      = $('#last').val(),
              addr1     = $('#addr1').val(),
              addr2     = $('#addr2').val(),
              city      = $('#city').val(),
              state     = $('#state').val(),
              zip       = $('#zip').val(),
              phone     = $('#phone').val(),
              phone2    = $('#phone2').val(),
              verified  = 'N';

               registermodel = new RegisterModel({
                   loginname     :  loginname,
              password  :  password,
              first     :  first,
              last      :  last,
              addr1     :  addr1,
              addr2     :  addr2,
              city      :  city,
              state     :  state,
              zip       :  zip,
              phone     :  phone,
              phone2    :  phone2,
                       verified  :  verified
                 });
               registermodel.save();
               return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is:

> Do not save `registermodel` if an error has been detected on the client-side.

Simply exit the `saveClient` function if an error has been detected (see `hasError` boolean):

```
saveClient: function (e) {

  var hasError = false;

  $('ul li').each(function(index){
    if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){
     alert('client side error found');
     hasError = true;
     return false; // this 'return false;' exits the .each loop function NOT the saveClient function
    }
  });

  if (hasError)
      return false; // this one does exit the saveClient function

  // Code continues here..
  // ...
}
```